# addplot3 markers problem and view understanding

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

[image: 3D view pictures]

I have added my lecture notes three figures `xelatex` script and three figures jpgs. Problems is I cannot show the `addplot3` markers in fractions. Same goes for 2D plots in figure 2 and 3. If you see the 3D figure 1 I want to show origin of x and y at one location I am not able to adjust view.

Lastly I am not able to show the text in xz plane and yz plane along the planes. I know its view adjustment but not able to do it.

Kindly if some body can help me in this regard. the data files are simple not included in code but can be understood from graphs.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{s.dat}
x   y   m 
1   1   0.33
2   1   0.33 
1   2   0.33 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{st.dat}
x   y   m
0   1   0.67
0   2   0.33 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{sth.dat}
x   y   m
1   4   0.67
2   4   0.33
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
 n   xn 
1   0.67
2   0.33 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Second.dat}
 n   xn 
1   0.67
2   0.33 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
[   scale = 2,
    view={45}{45},
    ticklabel style = {font=\large},
    xlabel={\huge $X$}, 
    ylabel={\huge $Y$},
    zlabel={\huge $p_{XY}(x,y)$},
    zlabel style={rotate=0},
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4},
    ymin=0,ymax=4,
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4},
    zmin=0, zmax=0.9,
    ztick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    zmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{m} \as \labela},
]
    \addplot3 [ycomb,scatter, mark = text,
              mark options={text mark=\labela,
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={scale=1.25, yshift=13pt}
                            }] table {s.dat};

\addplot3 [ycomb,scatter,color=red, mark = text,
              mark options={text mark={\labela},
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={scale=1.25, yshift=13pt}
                            }] table {st.dat};
\addplot3 [ycomb,scatter,color=orange, mark = text,
              mark options={text mark={\labela},
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={scale=1.25, yshift=13pt}
                            }] table {sth.dat};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    scale=2,
    ticklabel style = {font=\huge, color=blue},
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    every axis x label={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor= north west},
    every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=black},font=\huge},   
    xmin=0,
    xmax=4, 
    xtick={0, 1, 2, 3},    
    xticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$, $3$},
    % extra x tick style={ xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south} },
    xlabel={\huge $\boldsymbol{x}$},
    ylabel={\huge $\boldsymbol{p_X(x)}$},
    ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7},   
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.7,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{xn} \as \labela},
]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addplot+[ycomb,black,very thick,
      mark=text,
      text mark=\labela,
      text mark as node,
      text mark style={
        xshift=-9pt,
        yshift=20pt,
        font=\huge,
        }] table [x={n}, y={xn}] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    scale=2,
    ticklabel style = {font=\huge},
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    every axis x label={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor= north west},
    every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=black}},   
    xmin=0,
    xmax=4, 
    xtick={0, 1, 2, 3},    
    xticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$, $3$},
    % extra x tick style={ xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south} },
    xlabel={\huge $\boldsymbol{y}$},
    ylabel={\huge $\boldsymbol{p_Y(y)}$},
    ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7},   
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.7,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{xn} \as \labela},
]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addplot+[ycomb,black, very thick, mark=text,
      text mark=\labela,
      text mark as node,
      text mark style={
        xshift=-9pt,
        yshift=20pt,
        font=\huge}] table [x={n}, y={xn}] {Second.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,>=stealth,declare function={%
pfft(\x)=pi+0.3*sin(deg(\x));}]
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (5,0,0) coordinate(X) node[pos=1.1]{$x$};
 \draw[->] (O) -- (0,5,0) node[pos=1.1]{$y$};
 \draw[->] (O) -- (0,0,5) node[pos=1.1]{$z$};
 \draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=0.8*pi:1.1*pi,smooth] (2.2,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) 
 coordinate (T1)--
 plot[variable=\x,domain=1.1*pi:0.8*pi,smooth] (0.8,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) coordinate
 (T3)-- cycle;
 \draw (2.2,0.8*pi,0) coordinate (B4)-- (2.2,1.1*pi,0) coordinate (B1)
 -- (0.8,1.1*pi,0) coordinate (B2) -- (0.8,0.8*pi,0) coordinate (B3) -- cycle;
 \path (2.2,0.8*pi,{pfft(2*0.8*pi)}) coordinate (T4)
  (0.8,1.1*pi,{pfft(2*1.1*pi)}) coordinate (T2);
 \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
 {\draw (B\X) -- (T\X);}
 \path[opacity=0.3,left color=blue,right color=blue,middle color=blue!20,shading
  angle=72]
  plot[variable=\x,domain=0:1.1*pi,smooth] (3,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) --
  plot[variable=\x,domain=1.1*pi:0,smooth] (0,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) -- cycle;
 \path[opacity=0.3,left color=blue,right color=blue,middle color=blue!20,shading
  angle=72]
  plot[variable=\x,domain=1.1*pi:2.2*pi,smooth] (3,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) --
  plot[variable=\x,domain=2.2*pi:1.1*pi,smooth] (0,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) -- cycle;
 \draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:2.2*pi,smooth] (3,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) --
 plot[variable=\x,domain=2.2*pi:0,smooth] (0,\x,{pfft(2*\x)}) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, tdplot_main_coords,line cap=round,>=stealth,
    declare function={f(\x,\y)=3+0.5*sin(30*\x)*cos(30*\y);}]
 \draw[->] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (6,0,0) node[pos=1.05]{$x$};
 \node at (0.05,-0.15,0) [left,rotate=45]  {$x+\delta_1 x$};
 \node at (1,-0.15,0) [left,rotate=45]  {$\delta_1$};
 \node at (1.5,-0.15,0) [left,rotate=45]  {$x$};
 \draw[->] (O) -- (0,6,0) node[pos=1.05]{$y$};
 \node at (-0.25,2,0) [left,rotate=0]  {$y$};
 \node at (-0.25,3.3,0) [left,rotate=-5]  {$y+\delta_2 y$};
 \node at (-0.25,2.5,0) [left,rotate=0]  {$\delta_2$};
 \draw[->] (O) -- (0,0,5) node[pos=1.05]{$z$};
 \draw [pattern=vertical lines, pattern color=gray] (1,2,0) -- (2,2,0)   -- (2,3,0) -- (1,3,0) -- cycle;
 \foreach \X in {1,2} {\foreach \Y in {2,3} 
  {\draw[dashed] (\X,\Y,0) -- (\X,\Y,{f(\X,\Y)});}}    
 \foreach \X in {1,2} {
  \draw[dashed] (\X,2,0) -- (\X,0,0);}
 \foreach \Y in {2,3} {
  \draw[dashed] (1,\Y,0) -- (0,\Y,0);}
 \foreach \X in {0,...,4}
  {\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:5,smooth] (\X,\x,{f(\X,\x)});
  }
 \foreach \Y in {0,...,5}
  {\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:4,smooth] (\x,\Y,{f(\x,\Y)});
  }
 \draw[gray,thick,pattern=vertical lines, pattern color=gray] plot[variable=\x,domain=1:2,smooth]  (\x,2,{f(\x,2)})
    -- plot[variable=\y,domain=2:3]  (2,\y,{f(2,\y)})
    -- plot[variable=\x,domain=2:1]  (\x,3,{f(\x,3)})
    -- plot[variable=\y,domain=3:2]  (1,\y,{f(1,\y)})
    -- cycle;
 \draw (4,0,{f(4,0)}) -- (4,0,0);
 \draw (0,5,{f(0,5)}) -- (0,5,0);
 \draw (4,5,{f(4,5)}) -- (4,5,0);
 \draw (0,5,0) -- (4,5,0);
 \draw (4,0,0) -- (4,5,0);
 \draw (3,5,{f(3,5)}) -- (3,5,0);
 \draw (2,5,{f(2,5)}) -- (2,5,0);
 \draw (1,5,{f(1,5)}) -- (1,5,0);
 \draw [<-] (0.75,1,{f(0.75,1)}) -- (-3,1,3) node [pos=1.125] {$f_{XY}(x,y)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `/pgf/number format/frac`. The problem is that your file is not compilable, and perhaps more importantly not many will have your data file. So please make your code compilable and share all information that is needed to run it. (And what do you mean by " the data files are simple not included in code but can be understood from graphs"? Are we to invent some date ourselves?)

Comment: Hi Schrondinger's Cat, Thanks for reply, you have initiated this code learning for me. I have added the data files in the start. I think the code should run now.

Comment: Schrodinger's cat I think it should be running now I want to include these type of figures for my next lecture. How to use format/frac to convert markers into fractions. Thanks in advance

Comment: Really? Where is `\begin{document}`? Where is the data file `s.dat.txt`? Where is `\addfontfeature` defined? It would be so simple for you to just test if your file can be compiled rather than letting other try out. (The only thing that is a bit harder to check are the data files, there one can in principle see how someone could have them on their machine and forget to upload. However, all the other errors are hard to ignore.)

Comment: @Schrodinger's cat I just added the complete code of the pictures every bit and piece its running on my computer and generating the attached pictures. Nothing missing \begin{document} till end. All headers added too. Kindly if you can help me in my questions, I shall be grateful.

Comment: Tip: To markup code properly, select it and hit Ctrl + K (or click the button with `{}` above the text field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing compilable code! As for the "markers as fractions" problem, you can use

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac,/pgf/number format/frac denom=3}
```

together with `\pgfmathprintnumber`. For your convenience I made this a macro.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{s.dat}
x   y   m 
1   1   0.33
2   1   0.33 
1   2   0.33 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{st.dat}
x   y   m
0   1   0.67
0   2   0.33 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{sth.dat}
x   y   m
1   4   0.67
2   4   0.33
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
 n   xn 
1   0.67
2   0.33 
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Second.dat}
 n   xn 
1   0.67
2   0.33 
\end{filecontents}
\newcommand\PrintFrac[2][3]{%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac,/pgf/number format/frac denom=#1}%
\pgfmathprintnumber{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
[   scale = 2,
    view={45}{45},
    ticklabel style = {font=\large},
    xlabel={\huge $X$}, 
    ylabel={\huge $Y$},
    zlabel={\huge $p_{XY}(x,y)$},
    zlabel style={rotate=0},
    xmin=0,xmax=5,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4},
    ymin=0,ymax=4,
    ytick={0,1,2,3,4},
    zmin=0, zmax=0.9,
    ztick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    xmajorgrids=true,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    zmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{m} \as \labela},
]


    \addplot3 [ycomb,scatter, mark = text,
              mark options={text mark=\PrintFrac{\labela},
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={scale=1.25, anchor=south}
                            }] table {s.dat};

\addplot3 [ycomb,scatter,color=red, mark = text,
              mark options={text mark=\PrintFrac{\labela},
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={scale=1.25,  anchor=south}
                            }] table {st.dat};
\addplot3 [ycomb,scatter,color=orange, mark = text,
              mark options={text mark=\PrintFrac{\labela},
                            text mark as node=true,
                            text mark style={scale=1.25, anchor=south}
                            }] table {sth.dat};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    scale=2,
    ticklabel style = {font=\huge, color=blue},
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    every axis x label={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor= north west},
    every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=black},font=\huge},   
    xmin=0,
    xmax=4, 
    xtick={0, 1, 2, 3},    
    xticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$, $3$},
    % extra x tick style={ xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south} },
    xlabel={\huge $\boldsymbol{x}$},
    ylabel={\huge $\boldsymbol{p_X(x)}$},
    ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7},   
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.7,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{xn} \as \labela},
]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addplot+[ycomb,black,very thick,
      mark=text,
      text mark=\PrintFrac{\labela},
      text mark as node,
      text mark style={anchor=south,
        font=\huge,
        }] table [x={n}, y={xn}] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    scale=2,
    ticklabel style = {font=\huge},
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    every axis x label={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
    every axis y label={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor= north west},
    every axis plot post/.style={mark options={fill=black}},   
    xmin=0,
    xmax=4, 
    xtick={0, 1, 2, 3},    
    xticklabels={$0$, $1$, $2$, $3$},
    % extra x tick style={ xticklabel style={yshift=0.5ex, anchor=south} },
    xlabel={\huge $\boldsymbol{y}$},
    ylabel={\huge $\boldsymbol{p_Y(y)}$},
    ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7},   
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.7,
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{xn} \as \labela},
]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addplot+[ycomb,black, very thick, mark=text,
      text mark=\PrintFrac{\labela},
      text mark as node,
      text mark style={anchor=south,
        font=\huge}] table [x={n}, y={xn}] {Second.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Also, instead of all the hard coded shifts you can just adjust the anchors of these nodes, see the code above.

However, I fail to understand the second part of the question. Which texts are you talking about?

Comment: Superb humbly obliged.